# Return an array from a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

What is the proper way to return an array from a function in C? considering the caller doesn't know the size of the array, but without its size he cannot iterate over the array.

edit: just to clarify, the caller doesn't and shouldn't know the size of the returned array when calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

Return a struct where first element is the size and the second is the pointer to array.

```
struct size_and_array 
{
 int size;
 int* array; 
};
```

Comment: that's a possible solution but is it the optimal?

Comment: @CyberGK May not be. Dont know

Comment: @CyberGK Probably no worse than other methods of passing two values back to the caller.